# What is the best way to implement multiple filters AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple filters working fine over an ng-repeat. However, the code seems unnecessarily long to actually action the filters on a set and I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Here is an example filter - this bit I'm OK with (unless anyone has any advice) - they all follow a similar structure:

**app.js**

```
.filter('taskClient', function() {
    return function (items, clientId) {
        if (!clientId) { return items; }
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if (item.client) {
                if (item.client.id === clientId) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    }
})
```

And as I said - there are several of these. Then, on my ng-repeat, I implement them as so (**this is the bit that seems hard to maintain and overly long and would appreciate info on any better techniques**):

**tasks-index.html**

```
<md-list-item icp-task-line ng-repeat="task in TasksCtrl.tasks | taskOwner: TasksCtrl.selectedUserFilter | taskClient: TasksCtrl.clientId | taskDepartment: TasksCtrl.departmentId | taskPriority: TasksCtrl.priority | taskWithClient: TasksCtrl.withClient | taskEndDate: TasksCtrl.endDate | filter: {progress: 0} | filter: searchText | orderBy: TasksCtrl.orderTasks" class="md-2-line"></md-list-item>
```

Judging by how much scroll is involved here, I imagine you can see my issue with the above code. In order to get the length of tasks in view (also separated into completed, in progress etc) I have to list all the filters out again.

Is there a better way to implement these filters?

I'm also concerned that after reading [this article](https://toddmotto.com/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues/) I'm not understanding the difference between stateful and nonstateful filters - are the above filters optimised for performance?

Comment: Ok can you tell us the objective of having those many filter ? What are actually trying to achieve in the display process.If a sample demo is provided that would be great.

Comment: The brief was to be able to filter tasks by all of the above options - that's why they're there. However only one is applied on load - the others all through ng-models using checkboxes or drop downs.

Comment: There's a problem with using so many filters. It has to do with all the watches filters add. The more filters you pipe, the more watches you're going to have, which will result in poorer performance. I suggest you either implement a single filter that does all the tests, or a single filter that uses numerous factory filter methods instead (hold them in an array, and in the filter use 'forEach'). There are a lot of design patterns you can use for this. The important thing is to keep the number of chained filters to a minimum.

Comment: Great thanks - any chance you could put some code in an answer? Unfortunately these filters are all necessary and need to be used individually or as a combination of any number of them. I know they add too many watchers - in trying to work out a better way.

Comment: @eitanfar _"The more filters you pipe, the more watches you're going to have"_ That's definitely not the case with stateless filters.

Comment: @zeroflagL and my filters are "stateless" - correct? I removed all filters and the number of watchers did not go down.

Comment: Any filter that does not have the property `$stateful` is stateless. But I would rather use an already filtered list in `ngRepeat`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Any chance you could provide an example? Bear in mind the filters are adjustable by checkboxes and selects.

Answer (score 4):

you can combine all your similar filters into one, for example (I made very approximate assumptions about structure of your *task* model :), I inserted `filter: {progress: 0}` filter inside as well):

```
.filter('taskFilter', function() {
  return function (items, args) {
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      return (!args.selectedUserFilter || item.selectedUserFilter === args.selectedUserFilter) &&
             (!args.clientId || item.client && item.client.id === args.clientId) &&
             (!args.departmentId || item.department && item.department.id === args.departmentId) &&
             (!args.priority || item.priority === args.priority) &&
             (!args.withClient || item.withClient === args.withClient) &&
             (!args.endDate || item.endDate === args.endDate) &&
             item.progress === 0;
    });
  }
})
```

now HTML may look like

```
<md-list-item icp-task-line ng-repeat="task in TasksCtrl.tasks | taskFilter: TasksCtrl | filter: searchText | orderBy: TasksCtrl.orderTasks" class="md-2-line"></md-list-item>
```

Comment: Will this improve performance / reduce watchers? And will they work together?

Comment: 1. chaining filters in HTML means that output of one filter goes to the input of the next filter, each filter iterates over received array anew, combined filter will iterate only once. 2.  each filter registers a watch, combined filter will register one watch. 3. combined filter may work along with other filters, and its result is exactly the same as of chained in HTML filters. plunker with both kinds of filters - http://plnkr.co/edit/2XUlpSz702kqcjFXsMG1?p=preview

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I just came to review the answers and this seems to be the best answer. Only question I have is that removed my current chained filters does not seem to reduce the number of watchers - is this expected? Is there another performance benefit to your approach?

Answer (score 3):

I have two pieces of advice for you. First, if you want to get the filtered result in a variable so you don't have to apply all the filters again to get the count, you can add `as filtered_result` at the end of your filters and before any `track by...` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

My other advice to you is to not force the use of filters in the HTML. It *might* be better in your case to create a function that filters your `TasksCtrl.tasks` **once** and saves the results off to a `TasksCtrl.filteredTasks` property which your ng-repeat can iterate over with way fewer watches. If you want to keep the filtering code in Angular filters, you can inject `$filter` and run them manually in your function.

```
function filterTasks(){
    var tasks = TasksCtrl.tasks;
    tasks = $filter('taskOwner')(tasks, TasksCtrl.selectedUserFilter);
    tasks = $filter('taskClient')(tasks, TasksCtrl.clientId);
    tasks = $filter('taskDepartment')(tasks, TasksCtrl.departmentId)
    tasks = $filter('taskPriority')(tasks, TasksCtrl.priority);
    tasks = $filter('taskWithClient')(tasks, TasksCtrl.withClient);
    tasks = $filter('taskEndDate')(tasks, TasksCtrl.endDate)
    tasks = $filter('filter')(tasks, {progress: 0});
    tasks = $filter('filter')(tasks, searchText);
    tasks = $filter('orderBy')(tasks, TasksCtrl.orderTasks);
    TasksCtrl.filteredTasks = tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use javascript function `filter()`, which is really powerful:

```
.filter('taskClient', function() {
  return function(items, clientId) {
    if (!clientId) { return items; }
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.client && item.client.id === clientId;
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Other than chopping a couple of lines off (appreciate the info!) - that isn't changing the way the filters are applied - it's doing exactly what my current code is doing

Comment: No, it's really different: please compare `forEach` and `filter` docs... Or, try running the two implementations on quite big arrays, and see performance difference: it will be huge... :-)

Comment: Great - I will certainly do that and as I say I appreciate the info there - good to know. See editing question though where hopefully I've made it a bit clearer - it's the actual application of these filters - in the html ng-repeat that seems over the top to me and I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: OK, sorry. My answer is absolutely partial... :-( But do not underestimate forEach costs... :-)

Comment: Not at all - I hadn't explained my issue properly in the question at first! I'm currently changing my filters to use .filter instead!